# Wildcard or * for matching a datetime python 2.7

Tags: python

I am trying to match the following string and not having any luck. Below you will find my attempt.

```
LOG FORMAT: 
riskserver.2014-04-07-08:45:01.log
```

I think I only will need the year month and date.  So I was attempting a wildcard * which python 2.7 does not seem to like.

```
cmd = 'tail -n10000 /opt/rubedo/log/riskserver.'+nowFormat+*'
```

Help is very much appreciated here.  Thanks, I hope I explained this well, and some can understand.

I am using subprocess with grep involved.

```
tail: cannot open `/opt/rubedo/log/riskserver.2014-04-08' for reading: No such file or directory
```

grep: not: No such file or directory

```
EDIT:
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
nowFormat = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y\-%m\-%d")
```

Comment: The _shell_ interprets globs.

Comment: And it doesn't have __anything__ at all to do with `strftime`.  Edit the title.

Comment: Thanks any assistance?

Comment: Well we are not all pros at this, glob?  Are you saying to use use glob in my CMD code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glob is the splat (`*`) , eg `ls *.txt` gets processed by the linux shell into `ls f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt f4.txt ...`

so that `ls` actually recieves a list of files that match not the matching string. that is what they mean in the comments

```
nowFormat = "2014-04-07"
cmd = 'tail -n10000 /opt/rubedo/log/riskserver.'+nowFormat+'*'
os.system(cmd) #this will execute it through your linux shell you should see the output, allthough this call will not give you access to the output in python
```

or in python

```
import glob
fnames = glob.glob('/opt/rubedo/log/riskserver.'+nowFormat+'*')
print fnames
```