# String creation from list of values

Tags: python

In Python 3.4 I am trying to make a web crawler to check if a certain file is on a website. The problem is that the files can start with approximately 30 different names. (Some have 2 letters only, some have 3). I think my problem is similar to this ([Wildcard or * for matching a datetime python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942028/wildcard-or-for-matching-a-datetime-python-2-7)) but it does not seem to work in Python 3.4.

My basic code is like this;

`url_test = 'http://www.example.com/' + 'AAA' + '_file.pdf'`

What do I need to do to search from a prespecified list of values that should go where `AAA` is. They can be either 2 or 3 alphanumeric characters. A wildcard operation will also work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: If you already know the pattern and you already know the insert, why can't you just look for them all?

Comment: 30 isn't that many, just put them in a list and try each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
import string

for num_letters in [2, 3]:
    for chars in product(string.ascii_letters, repeat=num_letters):
        prefix = "".join(chars)
        url = "http://www.example.com/{}_file.pdf".format(prefix)
        # now look for the url
```

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that I understand the problem correctly, then this should do it:

```
for item in aaa_list:
    print 'http://www.example.com/' + item + '_file.pdf'
```

or, if you want to have a list of all possible values you can save that too:

```
urls = ['http://www.example.com/' + item + '_file.pdf' for item in aaa_list]
```